# XSLT1.0 with grouping or XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My Source File xml as follows:

```
<root>
     <bp>
         <id>999</id>
         <role>FL01</role>
         <comp/>
     </bp>
     <bp>
         <id>999</id>
         <role>FL00</role>
         <comp>123</comp>
     </bp>
     <bp>
        <id>999</id>
        <role>FL02</role>
        <comp>456</comp>
    </bp>
    <bp>
         <id>888</id>
         <role>FL01</role>
         <comp/>
     </bp>
     <bp>
         <id>888</id>
         <role>FL00</role>
         <comp>123</comp>
     </bp>
     <bp>
        <id>888</id>
        <role>FL02</role>
        <comp>456</comp>
    </bp>
</root>
```

I need to make final result as follows. It will split base on the `<comp>` and `<id>`. however, the `<bp>` without value `<comp>` the `<role>` require to add into each split.

```
 <root>
     <bp>
            <id>999</id>
            <comp>123</role>
            <role>FL01</role>
             <role>FL00</role>
        </bp>
    <bp>
            <id>999</id>
            <comp>456</role>
            <role>FL01</role>
             <role>FL02</role>
        </bp>
    <bp>
            <id>888</id>
            <comp>123</role>
            <role>FL01</role>
             <role>FL00</role>
        </bp>
    <bp>
            <id>888</id>
            <comp>456</role>
            <role>FL01</role>
             <role>FL02</role>
        </bp>
    </root>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: What is the principle of grouping the `bp` elements?

Comment: @Alexander: thanks for your reply. Apologies for my first time posting on this forum. I have a very basic knowledge on XSLT. Basically, I would like to achieve the result as shown above. I've tried using the grouping but didn't work.

Comment: I can not understand the principle of this grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1:** updated answer to reflect new requrements

(Note that I'm assuming you have your `<bp>` elements wrapped in a root-level element.)

If the order of each `<bp>`'s children isn't important, this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kBpByCompAndId" match="bp" use="concat(comp, '+', id)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*[normalize-space(comp)][
          generate-id() = generate-id(
            key('kBpByCompAndId', concat(comp, '+', id))[1]
          )
        ]"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bp">
    <bp>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*|key('kBpByCompAndId', concat('+', id))/role"/>
    </bp>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will produce a functionally equivalent result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <bp>
    <role>FL01</role>
    <id>999</id>
    <role>FL00</role>
    <comp>123</comp>
  </bp>
  <bp>
    <role>FL01</role>
    <id>999</id>
    <role>FL02</role>
    <comp>456</comp>
  </bp>
  <bp>
    <role>FL01</role>
    <id>888</id>
    <role>FL00</role>
    <comp>123</comp>
  </bp>
  <bp>
    <role>FL01</role>
    <id>888</id>
    <role>FL02</role>
    <comp>456</comp>
  </bp>
</root>
```

For reference, this XSLT makes use of a grouping technique called [Muenchian Grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping); since you are new to XSLT, this is a great technique to put in your toolkit.

Comment: ABach: Thanks for that. Looks good. however, if I add <bp> with different <id>, it didn't work. I have edited the sample data. Apologies for not giving a good data before.

Comment: @Handy: I've adjusted my solution and believe it should address your new requirements. Let me know!